# How to generate a list of mercurial branches in groovy?

Tags: groovy, mercurial, jenkins

How I can generate a list of remote mercurial branches in groovy? I want to add dynamic chooser parameter in Jenkins. Mercurial-server run as hgweb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hgweb-served Mercurial's repository list of it's branches can be obtained from `REPO-URL/branches?style=raw`

See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/branches?style=raw output as sample.

Comment: To parse this output, you could do: `def branches = new URL( 'http://selenic.com/hg/branches?style=raw' ).text.split( '\n' )*.split()*.head()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Extended choice parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) with the following Groovy script:

```
def hgUser = "user"
def hgPassword = "password"
def hgUrl = "repo_url"

def args = [
    "wget",
    "-q",
    "-O",
    "-",
    "https://" + hgUser + ":" + hgPassword + "@" + hgUrl + "/branches?style=raw"
];
def builder = new ProcessBuilder(args)
builder.redirectErrorStream(true)
def process = builder.start()

def branches = process.text.split("\n")*.split().findAll{
    it[2] != "closed" // Retain only non-closed branches
}*.head()
return branches.join(',')
```

Note that

- the script calls the `wget` command
- I provided the user+password authentication only as an example